# IBM Message Broker 6.1 configuration manager doesn't start

Tags: configurationmanager, messagebroker

After I installed fix pack 6.1.0-WS-MB-WinIA32-FP0011 the configuration manager throws a verification error at start.
It complains the java level:

> Verification failed. The required Java level ''1.5.0'' was not found.

The MQSI_JREPATH is set in mqsiprofile and in the PATH.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

> javaw.exe -Xshareclasses:destroy in the Message Broker Toolkit Directory /jdk/jre/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CVP process checks for a supported level of java before loading the copmonents. If you are sure that your java level is supported then you can disable this checking using the environment variable:

MQSI_DISABLE_CVP=1

Remember on windows you ened to set this in your mqsiprofile.cmd script and then start a new command window and restart the config manager.

On unix platforms you simply need to export the value in the shell before you start the config manager.

I would also advise doing a little problem determination, you can use the command "which java" on unix to determine the java installation being used. This should return a jre within the MQSI_FILEPATH folder

You can also do java -version to list the jre that the shell is picking up prior to launching the broker.

If after checking these you think that CVP is incorrectly identifying your java level as an unsupported version then I would suggest raising a PMR (but you can keep the env var set to diable CVP just to get you going.)